# Geocode Lat and Long On Form Save

Tags: python, django, google-maps-api-3, django-forms, google-geocoder

I'm trying to geocode the address on form save but, I'm having troubles.

Here is my model:

```html
class Restaurant(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='dispensary')
    restaurant_name = models.CharField(max_length=500, blank=False)
    phone = models.CharField(max_length=500)
    logo = models.ImageField(upload_to= 'dispensary_logo/', blank=False)


    #Location
    street_address = models.CharField(default = '',max_length = 50, null = True)
    city = models.CharField(default='', max_length = 254,null=True,blank=True)
    state = models.CharField(default = '',max_length=25, null = True)
    zip_Code = models.IntegerField(null=False, default='')
    lat = models.DecimalField(max_digits=18, decimal_places=10, null=True)
    lng = models.DecimalField(max_digits=18, decimal_places=10, null=True)


    def __str__(self):
        return self.restaurant_name
```

Here is the form:

```html
class RestaurantForm(forms.ModelForm):

    class Meta:
        model = Restauarant

        fields = ("restaurant_name", "phone", "logo", "street_address",
          "city", "state", "zip_Code")


    def save(self):
        if not self.lat or not self.lng:
            self.lat, self.lng = self.geocode(self.address)

            super(Restaurant, self).save()

    def geocode(self, address):
        address = urllib.parse.quote_plus(address)
        maps_api_url = "?".join([
        "http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json",
            urllib.parse.urlencode(street_address, city, state, zip_code)
    ])
    response = urllib.urlopen(maps_api_url)
    data = json.loads(response.read().decode('utf8'))

    if data['status'] == 'OK':
        lat = data['results'][0]['geometry']['restaurant']['lat']
        lng = data['results'][0]['geometry']['restaurant']['lng']

    return Decimal(lat), Decimal(lng)
         # Creates instance of form. Once the form is created, we can go back and edit that form.

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(RestaurantForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        if kwargs.get('instance'):
            self.fields['logo'].required = False
```

I keep getting the error that the "return Decimal(lat), Decimal(lng)"  is out of the function but, I'm not sure why. Any advisement would be appreciated.